# Django: How to add Chinese support to the application

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, translation, cjk

I am trying to add a Chinese language to my application written in Django and I have a really hard time with that. I have spent half a day trying different approaches, no success.

My application supports few languages, this is part of **settings.py** file:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Dublin'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LOCALES = (
    #English
    ('en', u'English'),

    #Norwegian
    ('no', u'Norsk'),

    #Finish
    ('fi', u'Suomi'),

    #Simplified Chinese
    ('zh-CN', u'简体中文'),

    #Traditional Chinese
    ('zh-TW', u'繁體中文'),

    #Japanese
    ('ja', u'日本語'),
)
```

At the moment all (but Chinese) languages work perfectly. This is a content of **locale directory**:

```
$ ls locale/
en
fi
ja
no
zh_CN
zh_TW
```

In every directory I have LC_MESSAGES directory with *.mo and *.po files.
*.po files are created by script written in Python, which converts *.ODS to a text file.
*.mo files are created by **python manage.py compilemessages** command.

Language can be selected by user from the proper form in "Preferences" section in my application.

Django does not load Chinese translation. That is the problem. Both simplified and traditional does not work. I have tried different variations of language and locale codes in settings.py and in locale directory: zh-CN, zh-cn, zh_CN, zh_cn. No success.

Perhaps I made a simple mistake? I have added Polish language just for test and everything went fine. Basically I did the same. I have added ('pl', u'Polish') tuple to the settings.py and "locale/pl" with *.po and *.mo and LC_MESSAGES directory...

Do you know what might be wrong?

Comment: Did you finally manage to find a solution to this? I am having the same problem with chinese - using only one dialect and defining them as ('zh-cn', gettext('Chinese')) in the settings file and naming the folder zh_cn in the locale dir

Comment: I finally managed to solve it, locally the dir in locale had to be named zh_cn but in the server it only worked when the dir in locale was named as zh-CN. Don't really know why...

Answer (score 19):

You will need to use lower case for your locale language codes for it to work properly. i.e. use

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('zh-cn', u'简体中文'), # instead of 'zh-CN'
    ('zh-tw', u'繁體中文'), # instead of 'zh-TW'
)
```

See the language codes specified in https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/conf/global_settings.py. You will see that it uses `zh-tw` instead of `zh-TW`.

Finally, the language directories storing the *.po and *.mo files in your locales folder needs to be named `zh_CN` and `zh_TW` respectively for the translations to work properly.

Comment: I have followed you advice and translation still does not work. But thank you for clarifying settings convention. Problem might be somewhere else in the application. I think it is even more probable now. I will keep investigating.

Comment: I just want to confirm quickly with you: in your settings.py file, do you have `LOCALE_PATHS` variable set? Also, do you have `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'` specified in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` variable?

Comment: Derek, thank you for you input here. Yes, I have `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` in the settings.py, but I do not have `LOCALE_PATHS` defined. I am working with Django 1.3 and as far as I understand Django looks for translation in **locale** directory inside the project. I think this feature is deprecated and will be removed in next releases of Django codebase, but it seems to work at the moment, because other languages works really well.

Comment: The really difference I can see now is the fact that Chinese requires two dialects. All other languages supported by the application (Japanese, Finish, Norwegian and Polish which I tested only) have one dialect only...

Comment: This did the trick for me! I have "zh-cn" in my settings.py, but I have to run "makemessages -l zh_CN". Thank you so much! This caused major frustration.

Comment: Actually that Github link now mentions "zh-hans" instead of "zh-cn"

Comment: Just a heads up. It's now `zh-hans` but not `zh-cn` anymore.

Comment: For simplified Chinese(`zh-cn`), it's `zh-hans` now. For `zh-hant`(Traditional Chinese), it's `zh-hant` now. `(Django 1.9 new update)`

Answer (score 12):

For Django 1.7 and up, you'll need to do the following:

`zh-hans` in your config, and make sure that your directory is named `zh_Hans`.

And for traditional Chinese:

`zh-hant` in your config, and your directory should be named `zh_Hant`.

Here is an example of how the `auth` contributor package lays out its translations in the locale directory: https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/auth/locale

Basically, for our Chinese language codes, the `-` is replaced with a `_`, and the first letter of the second work is capitalized.

Source code for this logic is here: [https://github.com/django/django/blob/7a42cfcfdc94c1e7cd653f3140b9eb30492bae4f/django/utils/translation/**init**.py#L272-L285](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7a42cfcfdc94c1e7cd653f3140b9eb30492bae4f/django/utils/translation/__init__.py#L272-L285)

and just to be thorough, here is the method:

```
def to_locale(language, to_lower=False):
    """
    Turns a language name (en-us) into a locale name (en_US). If 'to_lower' is
    True, the last component is lower-cased (en_us).
    """
    p = language.find('-')
    if p >= 0:
        if to_lower:
            return language[:p].lower() + '_' + language[p + 1:].lower()
        else:
            # Get correct locale for sr-latn
            if len(language[p + 1:]) > 2:
                return language[:p].lower() + '_' + language[p + 1].upper() + language[p + 2:].lower()
            return language[:p].lower() + '_' + language[p + 1:].upper()
    else:
return language.lower()
```

Note that `en-us` is turned into `en_US`, based on the source code above, because `us` is 2 characters or less.

Comment: A useful link is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/ , especially the [How Django discovers translations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations) part.

Comment: any reason why they did it this way? Seems like browsers put zh-tw header rather then zh-hans for users from China (see answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69709824/what-is-the-typical-chinese-language-code-for-the-accept-language-header )

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem [Django-1.6.1] and solved it by renaming the locale directories for Chinese from zh-cn (or zh_cn) to zh_CN (underscore and uppercase CN).

Strangely enough Django requires a "zh-cn" as LANGUAGE_CODE or url with an i18n_pattern respectively.

Non-documented goodness btw.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you were able to resolve this later, but the problem is with the language directory names in the locale directory. This happens with all languages with a dash in their short-code. The solution is to rename the Chinese directories by replacing the dashes with underscores:

zh-cn --> zh_cn
zh-tw --> zh_tw

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In .po file, add zh-cn or zh-tw in "Language: \n", which becomes "Language: zh-en\n" or "Language: zh-tw\n"

Compile the messages and runserver again.