# What is the typical Chinese language code for the Accept-Language header?

Tags: localization, internationalization, chinese-locale

Unfortunately, I have no way to check this personally, so I wanted to ask the community about it.

According to [RFC 5646](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4646.html), Chinese can have the following representation: `zh-Hans` for Simplified Chinese, `zh-Hant` for Traditional Chinese, or more specific: `zh-Hans-SG` for Simplified Chinese for Singapore, `zh-Hant-MO` for Traditional Chinese for Macau. This is not an exhaustive set of options, there are many.

One thing I know for sure - Chinese cannot be represented as follows: `zh`, or `zh-CN`, or `zh-TW` and the like.

However, how are things in reality? If the site is visited by a user who speaks Chinese, what can I expect in the Accept-Language header?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I got the Windows Sandbox installed and I was able to install whatever I wanted there.

I checked two browsers:

1. QQ browser (Chinese is selected by default, I'm not sure which
   script).
2. Google Chrome (added all supported Chinese languages ​​and
   made them first on the list).

QQ sends in the request the following content in the `accept-language` header: `zh-CN, zh; q = 0.9`.

Google Chrome sends the following content in the `accept-language` header: `zh-CN, zh-TW; q = 0.9, zh-HK; q = 0.8, zh; q = 0.7, en; q = 0.6`, also I figured out what Chrome means under the indicated codes:

- `zh-CN` - Chinese (Simplified)
- `zh-TW` - Chinese (Traditional)
- `zh-HK` - Chinese (Hong Kong)
- `zh` - Chinese

To be honest, this is strange, but it is a fact.